# PHP : strtotime() returns always 01/01/1970

Tags: php, date, format, strtotime

I am trying to display dates in the `European format (dd/mm/yyyy)` with `strtotime` but it always returns 01/01/1970.

Here is my codeline :

```
echo "<p><h6>".date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row['DMT_DATE_DOCUMENT']))."</h6></p>";
```

In my database, the field is a varchar and records are formated like **yyyy.mm.dd**

I use the same codeline for another field that is formated like **yyyy-mm-dd** (varchar too) and it works fine.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's probably because strtotime assumes mm/dd/yyyy instead and if you input a date like 13/2/2012 it complain that there is no 13th month and give you time 0 (1/1/1970)

Answer (score 4):

Since the format `yyyy-mm-dd` works, try to replace `.` with `-`:

```
date('d/m/Y', strtotime(str_replace('.', '-', $row['DMT_DATE_DOCUMENT'])));
```

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from [the strtotime page in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.

To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or `DateTime::createFromFormat()` when possible.

So in your case it should either be in format YYYY-MM-DD or d.m.y.

If you want to parse your custom format then use [date_create_from_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

For example,

```
date_create_from_format('Y.m.d',$row['DMT_DATE_DOCUMENT'])
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
$date = date_parse_from_format("Y.m.d", $row['DMT_DATE_DOCUMENT']);
$time = mktime($date['hour'], $date['minute'], $date['second'], $date['month'], $date['day'], $date['year']);
echo "<p><h6>".date('d/m/Y', $time)."</h6></p>";
```

(Using `date_parse_from_format()` instead of `strtotime()`)

Or just:

```
$date = date_parse_from_format("Y.m.d", $row['DMT_DATE_DOCUMENT']);
echo "<p><h6>{$date['day']}/{$date['month']}/{$date['year']}</h6></p>";
```

Comment: Yes, only that `date` won't accept the direct output of `date_parse_from_format`.